# Couldn't set authentication cookie lifetime - IdentityServer4

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

I am trying to set the `IdentityServer4` authentication cookie lifetime.
This is my client configuration :

```
// OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 120,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
                AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 120,

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:5002"
                },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
```

and my `Configure` method in the mvc client is

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            SlidingExpiration = false
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

I'm using the below sample from IdentityServer4 samples to learn IdentityServer4.
[IdentityServer4.Samples/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess)

I have already set the cookie expire time, access token life time, identity token life time and authorization code life time. But still the cookie life time is showing as session in the browser.
 Please see the below image

[image]

Am I missed any setting to do?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have tried both the solutions in that answer. But unfortunately it's not working. May be I should wait for an update.

Comment: To decide problem source: add `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event for openidconnect middleware  and debug project. Inspect the event when cookie expired. If the event is fired, it is authorization server issue. If not it is client application issue.

Comment: Or enable log and see if there is a redirect to identity provider(when cookie expired).